# Android how i can do GET request to my server every minute?

Tags: java, android

I simply need to do one get request every minute, also if my app in backgroud it must do too.
How i can to do it?

Comment: OT: This periodic GET request drains the battery, is there really a need to do this even while in background? See this page http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/regular_updates.html to consider different approaches if possible.

Comment: yes, i really need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule an intent service that will be launched periodically.
The intent service's onHandleIntent will run on a background thread, so you can perform your requests there.
Check [this link](http://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/using-intentservice-with-alarmmanager-to-schedule-alarms/) or [this link](http://androidtechlaunch.blogspot.it/2013/09/android-and-intent-service-for.html)

Comment: So i need to write 5 classes to do this task??

Comment: If you want to do it "the android way", which means having something that runs periodically even if your application is in background / not active, you have to use those components. If you can cope with a task that gets executed periodically when your app is in foreground, you can use a timer / handler + runnable, but it will be destroyed as soon as the os needs your app's resources.